# Extending Expiration dates of gnupg keys with the private key residing on a smart card

Tags: public-key-encryption, gnupg, public-key

I had setup a working smart card setup, where the local key ring solely contained public subkeys and secret keys resided on a smart card.

Conservatively I set the expiration date to 1 year.

Setup worked nicely and as the keys approached there expiration date, I proceeded as follows to attempt to extend their expiration date:

1. Kill running `gpg-agent`:

   ```
   pkill gpg-agent
   ```
2. Import offline master key (backup):

   ```
   gpg --import <KEYID>.master.key
   ```
3. Edit expiry of subkeys (pubkey):

   ```
   gpg --expert --edit-key <KEYID>
   ```

   - `toggle` keys 1, 2, 3 (sign, encrypt, authentication)
   - `expire`: 1y
   - `save`
4. Remove secret master keys:

   ```
   gpg --delete-secret-keys <KEYID>
   ```

As a result the keys remain unavailable (expired?) to all means I intent to use them with (kmail/kgpg/kleopatra, evolution/seahorse, etc.).

Where did I go wrong and how may I recover?

Comment: `gpg --list-keys` shows the (sub)keys with the correct expiration date (in the future, as intended); am I missing some secret key stub ?

Comment: `gpg --list-secret-keys` does not show anything ... need to get the secret key stubs pointing to the keys on the card back ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As evident from the comments above, I noted, that the secret keys were (no longer?) listed by `gpg --list-secret-keys`.

That was remedied by explicitly querying the reader-inserted smart card using `gpg --card-status`, followed by a now successful `gpg --list-secret-keys`.

After having pointed `evolution` at the now available secret key and removing the smart card from its reader, the mail client now (again) asks for insertion of the card when requesting signatures/encryption.

Works again. considered solved.